# Android gui controller Unity3D

Tags: android, user-interface, unity-game-engine, joystick

How do I implement the controllers (joystick) into unity3d? I'm building a very barebones game where the player moves around the x and z axis. I want the joystick to show up on screen.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to do? Unity already supports Joystick input: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.html

You can define custom input methods in the InputManger settings of the editor.